# Rewrite rule for urls with and without tracking string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently redirecting

```
info.myurl.com/should-you-be-worried-about-apples
```

To

```
www.myurl.com/landing-page/
```

It is working fine with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^info\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^should-you-be-worried-about-apples/$ http://www.myurl.com/landing-page/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

My problem is that should-you-be-worried-about-apples is also present on the site in multiple places with a tracking script attached to the end.

```
should-you-be-worried-about-apples?__hssc=&__hstc&hsCtaTracking=5a72d77e-2f14-4a70-bd75-47caf53582ac%7C849ebee6-7301-4822-9548-90eb9d5bf769
```

I can see that it has the variable 'hssc'. This is the commonality with all the tracking scripts. I've tried to rewrite it adding

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)hssc=
```

But that isn't working.

How can I write this so that it captures the standard url as well as any url with tracking attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just allow the query string to pass through:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^info\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^should-you-be-worried-about-apples/$ http://www.myurl.com/landing-page/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But if it's a matter of a specific parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^info\.myurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (^$|__hssc=)
RewriteRule ^should-you-be-worried-about-apples/$ http://www.myurl.com/landing-page/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, both options work well. Thank you. But now I'm finding that sometimes I have a / on the url and sometimes not...for instance sometimes it's apples/..sometimes apples?_hssc...sometimes just apples. So with your first option just apples doesn't get redirected. How do I get should-you-be-worried-about-apples with or without a backslash AND with a tracking variable to redirect?

Comment: I have it...^should-you-be-worried-about-apples/?$ Backslash, question mark, dollarsign. Thanks!